# vue.js and rails erb: How to place v-model tag inside erb input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, vue.js

I am currently trying to include a vue.js **v-model** into my erb form input tag and I cannot find the right syntax.

Here is how my code currently looks:

```
<div class="field">
   <%= f.text_field :first_name, v-model="firstname" %>
</div>
```

I would very much appreciate any idea here. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
<%= f.text_field :first_name, "v-model": "first_name" %>
```

Works for me

Answer (score 0):

FYI, for anyone else looking use Vue.js in ERB tags, @carlos-orellana's answer also works for:

`"v-on:click": "clickEvent"`

My guess is that it would work for most Vue bindings. Kudos to Carlos.