# Rails: v-model VueJS attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Inside a form tag i'm placing a hidden_field.
This hidden_field should have a "v-model" attribute.
I've tried all I can think about:

```
    # nothing shows up
    = f.hidden_field :model_attribute, "v-model" => "value"

    # that's the one I love the most: it compiles v="{:model=>"value"}"
    = f.hidden_field :model_attribute, v: { model: "value" }

    # it compiles with the underscore
    = f.hidden_field :model_attribute, v_model: "value"

    # this throws a compile error, obviously
    = f.hidden_field :model_attribute, v-model: "value"

    # guess the compiled outcome?
    = f.hidden_field :model_attribute, html: { "v-model" => "value" }

    #same as previous 
    = f.hidden_field :model_attribute, options: { "v-model" => "value" }
```

is rails screwing with me?
Can anyone help me?

Comment: It looks like the field helpers in rails 5.1+ enforce html5 compatibility, since you are using an invalid field, I don't think you can build the element using the helper, you'd need to write out the entire html tag.

Comment: You should think about why you want that hyphen, and whether or not you need it. I bet you have spent more time than you care to mention on this when you could have just used an underscore. So why not use an underscore?

Comment: to bind the vuejs to some field, one must use the "v-model" attribute. the underscore option is a fallback for when you are using data attributes, isn't it?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out @RafaelRavenaVicente

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not. But, since the engine (erb, slim, whatever) just compiles html, as a workarround I went by using the HTML compiler itself insted of the ruby pre-processor. For instance, in haml: %input.my_class{ type: "hidden", name: "model_attribute", v_model: "model_vue_binder", value: @value }/

Comment: this is a workarround, as said before, and could generate one of those unpredicted and untrackable bugs on "remodeling" event, for instance. If there's a migration that renames this given field, good luck finding this bug since it stops working, but doesn't generate a runtime error (yep, it should compile).

Answer (score 0):

When asking a question. You have to mention, it's **VueJS** attribute.

Check this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810949/vue-js-and-rails-erb-how-to-place-v-model-tag-inside-erb-input)

```
= f.hidden_field :model_attribute, "v-model": "val"
```

Comment: the expected rendering is <input type="hidden" name="model_class[model_attribute]" id="model_class_model_attribute" v-model="value" value=""/>, no data attributes needed.

Comment: yeah, it works great on select, text_field... just had trouble with rendering it on a hidden_field... just posted the question here when I was done trying to do it...